# Subscribe to a list while querying it to capture all items?

Tags: graphql

This is a conceptual GraphQL question, not tied to a specific client or server. If I have a list of some items and I want to query then and later subscribe to updates, how should I do it? First subscribe, then query or the other way around?

Imagine the following sample schema:

```
type Query {
    commentsByPostId(postId: ID!): String
}

type Mutation {
    addCommentToPost(postId: ID!, comment: String): String
}

type Subscription {
    commentAdded(postId: ID!): String
}

schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
    subscription: Subscription
}
```

A user clicks on the post. I want to get the list of existing comments and subscribe to future updates. I don't really want to do manual deduplication, but not missing updates is more important. So the best way to deal with it that I came up so far is to first subscribe to updates, then do a query and once the query results arrive merge them with the list of updates received so far. Are there better approaches?

Comment: "*list of existing comments*" - shouldn't `commentsByPostId` return a `[String]` then?

Answer (score 1):

### Approach A

Don't use a query at all. Just have your subscription return all comments that were ever added to a post. You collect them into a list at the client (as you do anyway).

There might be some overhead by transporting them individually, but it works just fine, with even less code on the client. On the other hand, it'll be hard to know for the client when the "initial" comments are done being received, and should be rendered the first time.

### Approach B

Send a token (e.g. a timestamp) with the query result, and have your subscription take the same as an argument to receive all events since.

```
scalar Cursor;

type Comments {
    continue: Cursor
    values: [String!]
}

type Query {
    commentsByPostId(postId: ID!): Comments
}

type Subscription {
    commentsAdded(postId: ID!, since: Cursor): String
}
```

Comment: That would be the ideal approach scenario, but I am not sure if it is implementable. I am actually using AWS AppSync and they only support subscription on mutation. Also I was reading GraphQL specs, if I read it right the subscribe is not supposed to return pre-existing records. It seems to be of a Pub-Sub semantics: https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Subscription "If the operation is a subscription, the result is an event stream called the “Response Stream” where each event in the event stream is the result of executing the operation for each new event on an underlying “Source Stream”.

Comment: Do you have experience implementing this pattern with any existing GQL servers?

Comment: @Andrey We have seen approach B. I have not used AppSync.

Comment: approach B still requires subscription to return pre-existing records. Because if I had a network delay between return of the query (cursor time) and the time I subscribe, it should first return all the comments added so far, so I am back with the same issue of how to make subscription return existing messages, which if I read correctly is not provisioned in the spec.

Comment: @Andrey There's nothing in the spec which would forbid that. Sure, subscriptions are event streams and *meant* to listen to presently occurring events, but it's not wrong to re-emit events that the client would have missed otherwise. You can of course put a limit on the cursors the subscription accepts, throwing an error if it's older than say 30s.